# how to put local website in local browser?

Tags: asp.net

In Win Server 2003, I would like to set the default IE homepage to a local website.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Unless you mean `http://localhost/`, your question is not really understandable as it is. Can you clarify it?

Comment: i made a asp.net website. i just want to open this site when i click on internet explorer on my system?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what depth of answer you are looking for. You dont need to do anything special. Go through any IIS setup tutorial and launch the browser with http://localhost url

Comment: i made a asp.net website. i just want to open this site when i click on internet explorer on my system?

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively straightforward to accomplish.

1. Open a new IE browser and navigate to your local website.
2. Click Tools | Internet Options
3. On the General tab, click the Use Current button under "Home page"
4. Click Ok